# Minimum board size for knights tour to be possible

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, knight-tours

What is the minimum board size for a knight's tour: open or closed, to be possible.

Edit: I want to write a program that can solve knight's tour for any board size. I want to implement a lower limit so that the program doesn't get stuck.

**I also want to know if it is knight's tour is possible on unequal indexes i.e 7x8, 9x7**

*Added by Alex Ravsky.* I think the question concerns a well-known ([its history has more than a thousand years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour#History)) and respected problem. The existence question is investigated and [completely answered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour#Which_boards_have_tours).  So I vote to undelete and reopen this question and then to make it answered.

Comment: 1x1 or 0x0 seem like good candidates

Comment: Not sure if you are trolling. For a knight to move, the minimum must be a 3x3 if the starting position is at a corner. I've read around and 5x5 seems to be minimum.

Comment: In fact, for a square board and ruling out the cases $0$ and $1$, the minimum is $5$. A closed tour is possible if and only if the number is even.

Comment: A tour on a 3 X 7 board is possible.  You might be interested in  "Selected Papers on Fun and Games" by Donald E. Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest rectangular board with open knight tours is the 12-cell 3 by 4 (three geometrically distinct found by Euler 1759).
The smallest rectangular boards with closed knight tours are the 30-cell boards 3 by 10 (the first found by Ernest Bergholt 1918) and 5 by 6 (three solutions, one asymmetric found by Euler 1759, and two symmetric found by others later).
See my 'Knight's Tour Notes' web-pages for complete diagrams.